# Unable to deploy edited Metadata using Mavensmate (Sublime Text)

Tags: metadata, mavensmate, sublime

I'm new to using mavensmate and deploying metadata using the metadata API in general but I was wondering if you could guide me in the right direction or confirm that this is an issue:

I've created a Project and been deploying metadata for a few days now but I'm getting the following permission error whilst deploying profiles: Unknown User Permission: EditReports.

I assume that this is because it is a legacy permission from the old org I am migrating from and therefore am trying to edit the src code within Sublime, pressing Save and then try to deploy again... But the errors are still showing exactly the same! The Project seems to have saved but MavensMate desktop isn't accepting the files maybe? Why is the error still showing?

Thanks in advance!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this was related to using a beta version of mavensmate and reverting to the standard version fixed the issue! I could save the changes straight back into the original Org and then deploy into the new org without issue! Thanks anyway!